# How to generate classes for multiple languages

Tags: javascript, java, c#, code-generation, mps

I am looking for a way to generate some model classes to multiple languages (Java, C#, JavaScript) to maintain consistency among these. Is there some tool which will help me define the model in one place and generate it after each change for all three languages? I was looking at [JetBrains MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/), but it seems to be useful for generating only one language, it is even written in documentation, that only one language generator (if any) is recommended.

Only way I found so far are XML files and XSL transformation for each language, but I am looking for more convenient way.

Answer (score 3):

If by "model" you mean classes that only keeps data, and you need consistency for serialization / deserialization, you should consider google protocol buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/ or similar solution.

For more sophisticated uses, you may consider writing in c and generate wrappers with swig: http://www.swig.org/, but is is extreme ;)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean by "model". I will take a look at the Protocol Buffers. Do you know some other "similar solution" - if you do, please update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the strictest sense, this is impossible, as some characteristics of those languages don't intertranslate.

For example, putting `delegate Method();` in C#, as you might well do when modeling something, it immediately breaks direct conversion to Java as Java has no notion of delegate methods.

Sure, both languages are Turing complete, so *theoretically* they *do* translate, but the translator would have to:

1. Compile the input language into a low-level enough language that both the input and the output language somehow share that language as an origin (might be Assembler).
2. Decompile that low-level language back up into one of the many equivalent forms in the output language.

Step 2 above is way too damn complex to do. (This is why you can distribute any of your C# as compiled EXE and not worry about someone stealing your source code.)

Comment: I should have emphasized the word "model" - by that I meant classes that only keeps data. I'm not trying to write a whole software on 1 place and compile it in N languages.